# Optimizing/learning function in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning

I would like to create a function that, given a list of integers as input, returns a boolean based on that number. I would like it to use an algorithm to find the optimum cut-off value that optimizes the number of correct returns.

Is there some tool built-in with Python for this? Otherwise, how would I approach such a problem using Python? Preferably, I would want to learn how to do both.

Comment: I am unsure what you are asking. You get a list of inputs, and return true or false based on that? What are the conditions that yield a true or false. I also don't know what you mean by optimizing the number of correct returns. What exactly is a correct return?

Comment: This seems to be an application of machine learning, Zachary. Perhaps looking into http://scikit-learn.org/ would be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be something that a linear machine learning algorithm could solve. In fact, the [Ordinary Least Squares linear classification model](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#ordinary-least-squares) seems to follow the exact outline you provide: it uses an algorithm to attempt to match it's output with your examples based on the numerical input, with the heuristic it attempts to minimize being a number of answers it gets wrong. If this is indeed the case, I believe scikit-learn will be the library you want. As to learning how this is done, the document linked above will at least get you started.